# GraphQL query to filter db document

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am writing an application using graphql, spring and mongodb. Here i want to perform some filter on db document using graphql.
Below is the representation of single document from mongo collection:

```
    {
        "data" : {
            "attribute1" : [
                {
                    "key":"val1"
                    "region":"US"
                },{
                    "key":"val2"
                    "region":"UK"
                }
            ]
            "attribute2" : [
                {
                    "nestedAttribute1": [
                        {
                            "key":"val3"
                            "region":"US"
                        },{
                            "key":"val4"
                            "region":"UK"
                        }
                    ]
                    
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I want to filter the document, using GraphQL, with all the data where 'region' is 'US'.
Expected output:

```
    {
        "data" : {
            "attribute1" : [
                {
                    "key":"val1"
                    "region":"US"
                }
            ],
            "attribute2" : [
                {
                    "nestedAttribute1": [
                        {
                            "key":"val3"
                            "region":"US"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to write a generic query across all the attributes?
If not, are there any alternatives to GraphQL which support this filtering.

Here is the schema that is exact representation for mongo collection
https://pastebin.com/JxEPEGhp

Comment: In JSON attribute1 and attribute2 structure is different . Filtering support is dependent on your mutation . Can you describe you problem in more detail ?

Comment: @Sumeet, Thanks for the reply.
Yes, attribute2 is an array of objects and each object can again have multiple attributes(like nestedAttribute1) that will have the same structure as "attribute1".
i am trying to write a microservice, where user will pass 'region' as an input parameter and in return it will get a document with all attributes with only given region's value(expected output as given in problem statement).